# Make title string the entire URI for all pages using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo

With CodeIgniter I'm trying to create a URL structure that uses a title string as the *entire* URI; so for example: *www.example.com/this-is-a-title-string*

I'm pretty confident I need to use the url_title() function in the URL Helper along with the routes.php config folder but I'm stuck bringing it all together.

Where do I define the URI and how is it caught by the routes folder?

Seems to be a straight forward problem but I'm getting stuck creating the URLs end-to-end. What am I missing?

I thought about a catch-all in the routes folder: `$route['(.*)'] = "welcome/controller/$1";` ....but how would this work with multiple functions inside a particular controller? ...and maybe it's not even the right way to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can send all requests to a driver with something like this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/function";
```

Then use the [_remap function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) to route requests inside the controller.

However, using URL's as you suggest limits the CI functionality. Try something better like **www.example.com/article/this-is-a-title-string**

```
$route['article/(:any)'] = "articles/index";
```

and in article (controller), use _remap...

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to re-route every request, you should extend CI_Router.

The actual implementation depends on what you're doing. If you customize CI_Router, you can do it AFTER the code that checks routes.php, so that you can keep routes.php available for future customization.

If the URI contains the controller, function, and parameters, you can parse it within your extended CI_Router and then continue with the request like normal.

If the URI is arbitrary, then you'll need something (file, db, etc) that maps the URI to the correct controller/function/parameters. Using blog posts as an example, you can search for the URI (aka post-slug in WordPress) in the db and grab the corresponding record. Then forward the request to something like "articles/view/ID".